# R: Why does strptime always return NA when I try to format a date string?

Tags: r, date

Here's some of my data, read in from a file names AttReport_all:

```
Registration.Date                 Join.Time                Leave.Time
1 Jul 05, 2011 09:30 PM EDT Jul 07, 2011 01:05 PM EDT Jul 07, 2011 01:53 PM EDT
2 Jul 05, 2011 10:20 AM EDT Jul 07, 2011 01:04 PM EDT Jul 07, 2011 01:53 PM EDT
3 Jul 04, 2011 02:41 PM EDT Jul 07, 2011 12:49 PM EDT Jul 07, 2011 01:53 PM EDT
4 Jul 04, 2011 11:38 PM EDT Jul 07, 2011 12:49 PM EDT Jul 07, 2011 01:54 PM EDT
5 Jul 05, 2011 11:41 AM EDT Jul 07, 2011 12:54 PM EDT Jul 07, 2011 01:54 PM EDT
6 Jul 07, 2011 11:08 AM EDT Jul 07, 2011 01:16 PM EDT Jul 07, 2011 01:53 PM EDT
```

If I do `strptime(AttReport_all$Registration.Date, "%b %m, %Y %H:%M %p", tz="")` I get an array of NAs where I'm expecting dates.

`Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "C")` returns "C"

`typeof(AttReport_all$Registration.Date)` returns "integer"

`is.factor(AttReport_all$Registration.Date)` returns TRUE.

What am I missing?

Here's version output, if it helps:
platform       i386-pc-mingw32
arch           i386
os             mingw32
system         i386, mingw32
status
major          2
minor          13.0
year           2011
month          04
day            13
svn rev        55427
language       R
version.string R version 2.13.0 (2011-04-13)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`strptime` automatically runs `as.character` on the first argument (so it doesn't matter that it's a factor) and any trailing characters not specified in `format=` are ignored (so "EDT" doesn't matter).

The only issues are the typo @Ben Bolker identified (`%m` should be `%d`) and `%H` should be `%I` (`?strptime` says you should *not* use `%H` with `%p`).

```
# %b and %m are both *month* formats
strptime("Jul 05, 2011 09:30 PM EDT", "%b %m, %Y %H:%M %p", tz="")
# [1] NA

# change %m to %d and we no longer get NA, but the time is wrong (AM, not PM)
strptime("Jul 05, 2011 09:30 PM EDT", "%b %d, %Y %H:%M %p", tz="")
# [1] "2011-07-05 09:30:00"

# use %I (not %H) with %p
strptime("Jul 05, 2011 09:30 PM EDT", "%b %d, %Y %I:%M %p", tz="")
# [1] "2011-07-05 21:30:00"
```

Comment: dstr <- gsub(" EDT$","",as.character(AttReport_all$Registration.Date)) and strptime(dstr, "%b %d, %Y %H:%M %p", tz="") worked, but I'm not sure what it was doing.  It's possible my mistake was the %m/%H substitutions.

Comment: Seems like my mistake was the %m/%H substitutions. Thanks.

Comment: Using `%m` when you should have used `%d` caused the `NA`.  Using `%H` with `%p` caused a more subtle error.